# Video is not displaying on google chrome with html5 video tag

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video, android-videoview

I am trying to play video on chrome browser, which has been recorded from android device.
video link is this https://mumbaistreet.s3.amazonaws.com/Roshani/Video/REC_1428044820068.mp4

Video is displayed on html5 with video tag, problem is video is not displaying but audio is playing.

Video codec is MPEG-4 Video, AAC

If i change codec video does not play on android device.

Answer (score 1):

That file contains video in MPEG-4 Part 2 format, which isn't supported by Chrome. You would need it to be in H.264 (aka MPEG-4 Part 10), or some other supported format, like WebM. H.264 should work on most Android devices, although I guess there might be some older devices that don't support it.